# wkhtml extra space above font

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, wkhtmltopdf

I have a problem with text on generating pdf document using wkhtmltopdf. Wkhtmltopdf not generate extra space above text.

Html page looks good (tested on Chrome, Firefox): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr8zP.png

PDF looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNiqe.png

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: MaidenOrange;
    src: url('/fonts/MaidenOrange.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/MaidenOrange.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/MaidenOrange.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/MaidenOrange.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; 
}
```

```html
<div style="  
  z-index: 99999;
  top: 565px;
  left: 242px;
  font-family: MaidenOrange;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 245px;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">
  Kalendarz
  <br/>
  <span style="color: #325E95">2015</span>
</div>
```

In this example I use MaidenOrange font.
Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Sorry for my english...

Comment: Have you tried setting the line-height in the CSS?

Comment: Yes, I tried. When I set line-height the same as font size the result is almost the same. The only difference is that the string "2015" on html document is a little lower.